# how to treat numpy array division zero error

Tags: numpy

I have numpy array with random number

```
a=([[7.2],      b=([[0],
   [2.3],          [1.3],
   [1.1]])         [1.1]])
```

and I want to divide a with b, so I write code

```
c=np.divide(a,b)
```

but if b array includes zero, it makes division error.
I want to keep this simple code, then how do I ignore that zero division error?

Refering my python book, I think try ,except ,finally statement will work, but I don't know 
to use them

Comment: [Did you see this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497891/python-getting-around-division-by-zero)

Comment: then it is something like
try:
      l = np.divide(a,b)
   except ZeroDivisionError:
      l = 0  
works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
    c=np.divide(a,b)
```

Exception handling may not be what you are looking for. Often, you simply want nans for 0/0, rather than ditching the whole computation. np.nan_to_num may also come in handy.